# WKWebView Load URL Which Use Post Function Can't Get Param

Tags: javascript, html, ios, post, wkwebview

My iOS App is using a `WKWebView` to load a webpage but it is having trouble. When the URL I use with a post function with a param the `WKWebView` load url can't get param. What should I do?

Comment: Please post your code for clarity.